# Set of points where multiplication is locally injective

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ be function $f(x,y)=xy$. I wonder if we can for any $(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2$ find some $\varepsilon$, such that $f|_{K((x,y),\varepsilon)}$ is injective.

For points of the form $(x,0), (0,y)$ we cant because for any $\varepsilon$, $f(\varepsilon/4,0)=0=f(-\varepsilon/4,0)$. But i can't seem to prove for other points.

Attempt:

Let's say $x \not = 0 , y \not = 0$ and let $\varepsilon$ be fixed.

well let's look at the numbers $(x+t,y+s)\in K((x,y),\varepsilon$) for some small $t,s$. We want 
$$
xy=(x+t)(y+s) \implies (y+s)=\frac{(x+t-t)y}{x+t}= y - \frac{ty}{x+t} \implies s= \frac{-ty}{x+t}
$$

Moreover i want $t^2+s^2 < \varepsilon$
$$t^2 + \frac{t^2y^2}{(x+t)^2} < \varepsilon$$

So i am looking at a point $t_0$ such that $g(t):=t^2 + \frac{t^2y^2}{(x+t)^2}-\varepsilon, g(t_0) < 0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that. Suppose that $f|_{B((x,y),\varepsilon)}$ is injective. Then $B((x,y),\varepsilon)$ would be homeomorphic to its image. But its image would be an open interval of $\mathbb R$, and therefore they cannot possibly be homeomorphic.